# Python regex in lists

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a lists which contains the lists of different softwares that are build in the build-server. I want the specific one only. I have written the regex for it but getting the empty string. The code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

lists = ['sw_apple-mc-stded-date.dat', 'sw_apple-mc-prod-date.dat', 'sw_android-mc-prod-date.dat', 'sw_android-mc-stded-date.dat']
regex = re.compile('sw_apple-mc-stded')
for list in lists:
    firmware = regex.findall(list)
return firmware
```

I am getting an empty list firmware instead of 'sw_apple-mc-stdeb-date.dat'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `stded` isn't `stdeb`.

Comment: you do realize you don't need a regex to crack this one? (unless we are missing details...)

Comment: `regex.findall(list)` maybe? BTW both `file` and `list` are a poir choice of name. They mask the built-in with that name.

Comment: Also your code will only return the result of your last check, nothing else.

Comment: Made the changes accordingly. Please check the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findall()` will only return the matching part of the string. The bigger problem is that you are overwriting `firmware` in every loop iteration, which is why it is empty in the end if there is no match in the last list element:

```
regex = re.compile('sw_apple-mc-stded.*')  # add wildcard at the end to match entire string
firmware = []
for list in lists:
    firmware.extend(regex.findall(list))  # extend as findall returns a list
return firmware
```

However, for this task, I think a simple contains-check will do:

```
prefix = 'sw_apple-mc-stded'
firmware = [s for s in lists if prefix in s]
# firmware = [s for s in lists if s.startswith(prefix)]
return firmware
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using `regex = re.compile('sw_apple-mc-stdeb')` when you can simply check if there is a string match withing your list items

```
weird_lists = ['sw_apple-mc-stded-date.dat', 'sw_apple-mc-prod-date.dat', 'sw_android-mc-prod-date.dat', 'sw_android-mc-stded-date.dat']

for item in weird_lists:
    if "sw_apple-mc-stded" in item:
        print item
```

In your code, by doing:

```
for list in lists:
    firmware = regex.findall(list)
return firmware
```

return firmware returns you the list of item from the last iteration if it matches your "regex", since there is only 1 item and it doesn't match your "regex" the returned list is empty. if you add a print to your code you will see that the first iteration returns the list item and then three empty lists

Comment: what are you expecting? the result is 'sw_apple-mc-stded-date.dat'

Comment: I am expecting the string 'sw_apple-mc-stded-date.dat'. But getting empty string. Thanks.

Comment: the approach you are using is not really worthy of using Regex. As @Klaus D. mentioned, it returns an empty list, because you iterate through all the list items and do a findall 1 by 1, the last item doesnt match so the list is empty